# Why use a Pointer and its dereference in if statement in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I was looking for some c++ code, and was confused by `if(ptr && *ptr)`, what does it do in this case?

```
// Process the data here.  We just break the data into separate pieces and 
// display it for the sake of simplicity.
char * a_pszBreak = NULL;
char * a_pszDataItem = (char*)s_aucDataBuffer;
do
{
    // The poll data is terminated by either a Carriage Return alone, or a
    // Carriage Return/Line Feed pair.
    a_pszBreak = strpbrk(a_pszDataItem, "\n\r");
    if (a_pszBreak && *a_pszBreak)
    {
        *a_pszBreak = 0;
        a_pszBreak++;
        LogPollData((const char *)a_pszDataItem);
    }
    a_pszDataItem = a_pszBreak;
} while (a_pszBreak && *a_pszBreak);
```

Comment: It's a method to prevent incorrectly dereferencing a null pointer. The && short circuits, so if `ptr` is NULL `*ptr` is never attempted (it would segfault if it did).

Comment: You do know that you can dereference (with the dereference operator `*`)  a `NULL` pointer? And you do know that  the logical operators `&&` and `||` do [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)? And you know that a `NULL` pointers is considered as "false"? And you know that strings are terminated with a zero? And that any non-zero thing is considered "true"? If you know all those five things then put that knowledge together and think a little bit more.

Comment: Don't use pointers in C++. It's not 1995 any more. The code you are reading is highly antiquated.

Answer (score 6):

it means that the pointer should point to something and in addition that something must be different from 0.

It's like  `(a_pszBreak != nullptr && a_pszBrealk[0] != '\0')`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a_pszBreak && *a_pszBreak)
```

In C++, anything that can be interpreted as 0 is false and anything else is considered true for the purpose of statements.

So this ensures that the pointer is not *NULL* and that the contents of the first element the pointer points to is not *null* or 0 either.

Due to short circuiting, if the pointer **is** *NULL*, the second part will not be checked.

So in plain english, this `if`-statement checks if the pointer is not a `nullptr` **and** if the pointer does not point to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

In  `if (a_pszBreak && *a_pszBreak)` `a_pszBreak` is used to check whether `a_pszBreak` points to valid memory area i.e `a_pszBreak` is not NULL and `*a_pszBreak` is used to check whether memory pointed by `a_pszBreak` does not start with NULL character i.e `\0`.

In short `if (a_pszBreak && *a_pszBreak)` is used to check whether `a_pszBreak` points to a string of length atleast 1.

Comment: Actually `if (a_pszBreak)` doesn't give you any guarantees that pointer is valid, only that it is not `nullptr` so that actually holds an address. Whether that address is valid or not is a different story.